# Rotating an array with slices and tuple assignment

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve the LeetCode problem [189. Rotate Array](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotate-array/) in Python:

> Given an array, rotate the array to the right by k steps, where k is non-negative.
>
> ```
> class Solution:
>     def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
>         """
>         Do not return anything, modify nums in-place instead.
>         """
> ```

The following code works:

```
n = len(nums)
k = k % n
nums[k:], nums[:k] = nums[:-k], nums[-k:]
```

But if I change the order of the assignments in the last line, i.e. replace it with

```
nums[:k], nums[k:] = nums[-k:], nums[:-k]
```

the code doesn't work for the case of `k=0`. Clearly in this case, `nums[:k]` and `nums[:-k]` would be empty and the sizes of the lists on the left hand side and the right hand side don't match, but somehow the first code works and the second one doesn't.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

The order in which the tuple assignment is executed, is indeed relevant here.

Let's say `nums` is `[1,2,3,4]` (and `k` 0)

Then the non-working assignment comes down to this:

```
nums[:0], nums[0:] = [1,2,3,4], []
```

...which is executed in this order:

```
# First the right hand side expressions are evaluated
complete = [1,2,3,4]
empty = []
# Then these values are assigned to the left hand side
nums[:0] = complete
nums[0:] = empty
```

Note that the second phase has no magical *simultaneous* assignment: these assignments happen in a left-to-right order.

It is now clear that the latter assignment destroys the effect of the first. It is also clear if they were executed in the opposite order, the end result would be fine.

So the order of assignments matter, even in tuple assignments.

The deeper reason why the behaviour is different specifically when `k` is 0, is related to how `-k` works in a slice notation: this always counts `abs(k)` steps backwards from the end, **except** when `k=0`: then it represents the very first index.

You would not have this different behaviour if you would do this:

```
nums[:k], nums[k:] = nums[len(nums)-k:], nums[:len(nums)-k]
```

Now it is explicit that the index should be determined by stepping backwards from the end, **even** when `k` is 0. This tuple assignment can be swapped, and it will still work, also for `k` equal to 0.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I always thought that whenever we have tuple assignments in Python, the right hand side is evaluated first and then the values are assigned to the tuple of the variables to the left, so the order would be irrelevant. Isn't that the case?

Comment: What you describe is correct: the right hand side is evaluated first. But that is not the issue here. It is the order of assignment at the left hand side that is at stake here. There are two assignments and they obviously happen in a certain order. Since the second assignment empties the list, the effect of the first assignment is lost. So it is not about the order of evaluation of the *values*, but the effect of an assignment on the list structure.

Comment: I have updated the part in my answer where it says *"which is executed in this order:"*, so you can see the evaluation of the right hand side really happens before any assignment. But the actual assignment itself also happens in a left-to-right order. They don't happen *at the same time*. And since the second assignment empties the list, there is just no way the first assignment is retained.

Answer (score -1):

Well, consider this:

```
nums = [1, 2, 3]

nums[:0], nums[0:] = [1, 2, 3], []
print(nums)
```

Given the next to last line, what would you expect `nums` to be? The problem is that the statement is ambiguous to begin with and it just happens to be that the second implementation gets you an undesirable result - it resets the entire list to `[]` *after* adding `[1,2,3]` to the start. The first implementation does it the other way around.

What you were really after:

```
nums = nums[k:] + nums[:k]
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but this solves a different problem. The original problem is to *rotate* a list. You have created a new list that is the rotation of the original list. There is a slight difference  (mutation versus new).

Comment: Although that's definitely true, I would note that the original question linked by OP doesn't require that the rotation be in-place, although for very large lists that would be a good attribute for a practical rotation.

Comment: I agree that it was not explicitly mentioned in the original question, but the link to LeetCode made clear this was intended -- as this is mentioned in the template code provided on LeetCode. Sure enough, the Asker should have quoted that LeetCode challenge and not only have linked to it.

Comment: @Grismar *"the original question linked by OP doesn't require that the rotation be in-place"* - Doesn't it? It says *"modify nums in-place"*.

Comment: @Kelly, to be fair, that was not mentioned in the original version of the question. It could only be found on the linked website.

Comment: @trincot Yes, but Grismar says that *"the original question **linked by** OP"*, i.e., the *LeetCode* question, doesn't say so.

Comment: Sorry, I should've simply added the question and code template to the OP. It was my very first post here!